# Pushing logs over HTTP is not working in sumo logic

Tags: http, sumologic

I have created source, category and generated the URL but when i am trying to post the data, it is not reflecting in the sumo logic live tail.

API is giving the 200 response.
No errors

[image]

Comment: "it is reflecting in the sumo logic live tail" is there a word missing? Not reflecting?

Comment: Thanks. i corrected it. it is not reflected

Comment: The URL in your screenshot - it doesn't look like the full URL, just the prefix of it. Not sure if this is you redacting the secret for posting to Stackoverflow or the actual value you are trying.

Comment: Intentionally removed the actual endpoint. I cannot pulically expose my key.